# Building maven project with custom version of artifact instead of the one from repo

Tags: java, maven, jboss, maven-3

I'm new to maven, sorry for nub question: **need to build maven project using my version of artifact instead of the one from repo**.

**More detailed:**
I downloaded jboss sources from github and built them using maven 3. It was great! I need to do some changes in jboss dependancy called "picketbox". Now it is an artifact in jboss's "pom.xml".

I built my own version of picketbox in my_picketbox.jar file. **How can I tell maven to use my .jar instead of the one from repo?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but if you explicitly renamed the artifact then it will just be a matter of replacing `picketbox` with `my_picketbox`in the relevant JBoss POM-file(s).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_picketbox</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

And of course, you make sure your artifact is in your local repo by `mvn install`'ing it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

i would install the jar file using the maven-install plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Answer (score 2):

First, install your version of Picketbox into your local Maven repository. If your custom version is a Maven project, you can do that by running

```
mvn install
```

If your custom Picketbox version is not a Maven project, install the Jar itself into your local Maven repository like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=my_picketbox.jar -DgroupId=org.picketbox -DartifactId=my_picketbox -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then change the version of Picketbox that JBoss depends on by adding this snippet to the `pom.xml` file of the JBoss project you're building (replace the existing dependency on pocketbox with this one):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_picketbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/xxxx.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This allows you to reference libaries that are not stored localy rather than maven central.

Answer (score 0):

Maven takes what has been specified in POM files; mind you, that the POM including the dependency you wrote about can be buried very deeply, not even within the sources you downloaded.

Search your project tree for the artifact in question and replace its version number to your version. If this does not help, do as Nils says in the other answer, but remember to install the artifact in the **original version** (you may have to find it first in your local repository and remove it).